# Rails - Retain form values on failed submission. Getting "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First Rails question! Loving it so far. :D

I know this has been asked multiple times but none of the answers worked for me. When a signup fails, I'd like to go back to the old form and retain the old form values. I know I'm suppose to render the same view on failed attempt but for some reason it doesn't work.

Here's my form in the `signup` view

```
<%= form_for(@new_user, :url => {:action => 'attempt_signup'}) do |f| %>
    //form fields like :name, :email, :password
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def signup
    @new_user = User.new
    #some code to populate form fields.
end
def attempt_signup
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to(:controller => 'static', :action => 'index') #this works
    else
        render :action => 'signup' #this doesn't
    end 
end
```

This works well, if there are no validation errors and user successfully signs up but I get the error if signup fails due to some validation error.

I think I understand the problem which is that on rendering signup again after a failed attempt, none of the controller code in the `signup` action runs again, since I'm just rendering. Because of this, `@new_user` isn't defined. But I don't know how to solve this. If signup fails due to validation error, instead of going back to the old form, I get the error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`. So how do I solve this and retain the filled values as well?

Also, I don't understand how just rendering the view back would repopulate the form fields with the previous values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to

```
def attempt_signup
    @new_user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @new_user.save
     ....
      .....
```